# Custom WCF REST Service Hosted in SharePoint 2013

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I followed this wonderful post 
[SharePoint 2013: Create a Custom WCF REST Service Hosted in SharePoint](http://sharepoint.softwaredevelopmentoutpost.com/2014/04/sharepoint-2013-create-custom-wcf-rest.html)

Now when I call a "GET" request everything work as expected. My problem with  "POST" request, it always return 404 not found error response!

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke( Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "Approve",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool Approve(PendingMeRequest pendingRequest);
```

Approve implementation is simple and return true

```
    public bool Approve(PendingMeRequest pendingRequest)
    {
        return true;
        //SPUser currentuser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
        //return Take_approval_action(pendingRequest, "approve", currentuser.LoginName);
    }
```

PendingMeRequest Model is simple with 3 string fields

```
public class PendingMeRequest
{
    public string Key { set; get; }

    public string RequestedBy { set; get; }

    public string RequestTitle { set; get; }
}
```

When I call this method with jquery I get 404 not found error

```
 $.ajax({
          url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_vti_bin/UnifiedWorklistService.svc/Approve/',
          method: 'POST',
          dataType: 'JSON',
          data: JSON.stringify({pendingRequest: obj}),
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          success: function (data) {
              alert(data);
          }
 });
```

I tried to call it from POSTMAN but I got the same error

I think i miss something with Sharepoint configuration but I cannot figure it out

**UPDATE:**

After few hours of searching finally I found the problem, it is the trailing slash in the ajax call `/_vti_bin/UnifiedWorklistService.svc/Approve/` should be removed!!

I cannot believe the time I wasted to figure it out...

Comment: You need to add more details.. anyway have you try to call the service url with browser ? Try to capture the network traffic to see the called url.

Comment: What is the missing details, I tried to call using postman and with jquery post, the response is 404 not found in both cases. if I changed it to GET request (and change the parameter to Int) it work and I get server response

Comment: Activate tracing to get more error details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Maybe you can add the url you call (hiding the hostname) and the namespace and class name contains the Approve method, also the ajax test, also you can try the call from browser and capture the network traffic, include the fiddler traffic, show the content of the .svc file.

Comment: Please edit you question and add the javascript code you use to post the request.

Comment: I edited my question to include all my implementation, passed model and jquery call